# Initialise model object from table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

Is there a way to instantiate a namespaced model object from its table name?

eg: Given table `school_students`, model `School::Student`, id `30`, I could do:

`student = get_from_table_name_and_id("school_students", 38)`

Answer (score 0):

This implementation should work

```
def get_from_table_name_and_id(klass, id)
  klass.gsub('_','/').classify.constantize.find(id)
end
```

an output :

```
irb(main):004:0> "school_students".gsub('_','/').classify                                                                                                                            
=> "School::Student"
```

The naming convention on Rails is a namespace is represent by a `/` in String

Comment: Why it's works with my example so ? You send us valid value or you try with another ?

Comment: Consider a model like `School::StudentSettings`

Comment: Yes its doesn't works because it's impossible to know if you your _ is a Namespace of Class. You can do that but you need test several possibility before and choose the right. But can have more than one possibility.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I was wondering if there was an other option other than string manipulation.